# Illegal operation on empty result set - how to check if it's empty?

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I've got a problem with my Java plugin - when there's no results found it says that result set is empty. Could someone tell me how to detect if result set is empty?

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs;
String p = pp.getName();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE username='"
        + p + "' AND recieved=0 ORDER BY id DESC");
rs = stmt.getResultSet();
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? How are you consuming the `ResultSet`?

Comment: See: http://sscce.org/ and update your post to a more understandable question.

Comment: Thats my code:
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            String p = pp.getName();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE username='" + p + "' AND recieved=0 ORDER BY id DESC");

Comment: And then i do that to get result 
rs = stmt.getResultSet();

Comment: The exception stack trace tells exactly where this exception is thrown. Post this stack trace, and the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach is to attempt to get the next row using the `next()` method, and check if it returned `false` (meaning there is no next row, so it's empty). Like this:

```
ResultSet rs;
// run query on database
if (!rs.next()) {
    // no row(s) found from database
} else {
    // row(s) found from database OK
}
```

It can be convenient to code a `do...while` loop:

```
if (!rs.next()) {
    // handle no rows found
} else {
    // process all rows
    do {
        // process row
    } while (rs.next());
}
```